# how to use --selector & --defer in getdbt. Please share some examples

Tags: analytics, data-warehouse, dbt

I am using getdbt on redshift for data analytics operation. Can anyone please suggest, how to use --selector & --defer with "dbt run" commands.
What is the syntax ? What is the use of selectors.yml file?
Please share some examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of `defer` is a way to utilize the dbt cli to work with unbuilt or differential versions of the current & futures state defined versions of a model.

Example of why you may want to interact with that here: [#2740 - Automating Non Regression Test](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/2740)

---

`selectors` being a relatively new feature, I also haven't seen much documentation to back this up but it is effectively a naming convention for a set of logical criteria (more than 1 tag, multiple directories, etc.)

I'd recommend this article in general for understanding the build path generation of a typical dbt run: [How we made dbt runs 30% faster](https://blog.getdbt.com/how-we-made-dbt-runs-30-faster/)

From there, you can imagine that within a large project, there are huge interconnecting chains for each raw -> analytics ready transformation pipeline that you have.

We'll use Gitlab's open [dbt project](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-data/analytics/-/tree/master/transform/snowflake-dbt) as an example.

Gitlab doesn't currently use selectors but they do make use of tags.
So they could build up a `selectors.yml` file using logical definitions like:

`selectors.yml`

```
selectors:
  - name: sales_funnel
    definition: 
        tag: salesforce
        tag: sales_funnel
  - name: arr
    description: builds all arr models to current state + all upstream dependencies (zoho, zuora subscriptions, etc.)
    default: true
    definition: 
         tag: zuora_revenue
         tag: arr
  - name: month_end_process
    description: builds reporting models about customer segments based on subscription activity for latest closed month
    definition:
      - union:
          - method: fqn
            value: rpt_available_to_renew_month_end
            greedy: eager  # default: will include all tests that touch selected model
          - method: fqn
            value: rpt_possible_to_churn_month_end
            greedy: eager
```

Full list of valid selector definitions here: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/yaml-selectors#default

What that gives them the ability to do is on a cron job, via airflow, or some other orchestrator simply execute:

`dbt run --selector month_end_process --full-refresh`

And have confidence that the logical selection of models to run for that process is 100% accurately reproduced instead of another more fallible  approach like assuming that all the models needed are in a single directory:

`dbt run --models marts.finance.restricted_safe.reports --full-refresh`

---

Architecturally, you likely won't need selectors until you get to the level of having multiple layers of tags and / or multiple layers of use-case directories to be mindful of within a single run.

Example: tags for the models' function, tags for the sources, tags for the bi/analyst consumers, tags for the [materialization schedule](https://www.getdbt.com/coalesce-2021/optimizing-query-run-time-with-materialization-schedules/), etc.